# Keeps saying "./bin/main : the term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet... "

Tags: c++, compilation

I tried compiling a basic C++ program that prints out hello world in VSC. I have installed TDM GCC and also made the path modifications. The terminal also says undefined reference to 'winmain' when I try to compile my program. What could the problem possibly be?

Comment: Have you tried searching for another question? Try searching for the term, undefined reference to winmain. I think you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to compile it exactly?
If you're stuck I can recommend this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Basically, you can go to **Terminal** > **Run Build Task** and should be able to choose the compiler from there. The **Terminal** menu is at the top between the **Run** menu and the **Help** menu. You can also just press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + B</kbd> to **Run Build Task**.

Comment: g++ ./src/main.cpp -o ./bin.main ; ./src/bin.main I compiled using this

Comment: I also tried doing "run build task" but it just says build finished successfully and nothing

Comment: You can try "g++ --version" to see if g++ is actually recognized in your terminal/powershell. But it sounds like "Run build task" worked for you, now you should have a main.exe or whatever your filename is in the same folder. You can run by pressing F5 in VS Code (after setting up the Debug/Run configuration as described in the link I posted above).